# Getting data in an Angular Component (Profile page)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, rest, jwt

I'm working on a MEAN Stack application. I have made authentication and authorization using jWt and it works like a charm.
The problem that I'm facing is how to get the user data in the Profile page component. I'm thinking about several options:

- First, sending the email from the ***Login*** component to the ***Dashboard*** and then pass it to ***Profile***. It will be easy from then to send a get request to get the user with the email.
- Second, I don't know if it possible but I'm thinking of using the **jwt** I'm returning to the user to get his data since I created it with the provided **email** in *Login*

This is how I created the jwt token:

```
login: async (data, model) => {
    try {
        /** 
         * Fetch the admin from the Database
         */
        const adminData = await baseRepository.findOne({ email: data.email }, model);
        /** 
         * Check if an admin with that email exists
         */
        if (!adminData) {
            return (400, { message: "ADMIN NOT FOUND" })
        } else {
            /** 
             * Compare the input password with the hashed password in the database
             */
            const admin = { email: adminData.email }
            if (await bcrypt.compare(data.password, adminData.password)) {
                /** 
                 * Create a jwt Token and send it back to the client
                 */
                const accessToken = jwt.sign(admin, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
                return ({ status: 200, accessToken: accessToken })
            }
            return ({ status: 401, accessToken: null })
        }
    }

    catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

That's the method from the repository that I'm using to handle the request in the controller this way:

```
login: async (req, res) => {

    try {
        console.log("yo")
        const { status, accessToken } = await authRepository.login(req.body, Admin)
        if (status == 400) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: "ADMIN NOT FOUND" })
        } else if (status == 401) {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "WRONG PASSWORD" })
        }
        res.status(200).json({ accessToken: accessToken })
    }
    catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: e })
    }

}
```

And these are the libraries I'm using:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
```

Comment: Can you include segments of code, including the jwt libraries you're using? It's common to have a service holding the profile data returned on the login action. Then components like Dashboard or Profile take it from there without needing query params. I'm using auth0 auth services, which are JWT based. My auth service uses their js SDK, which returns me some basic profile info, including email.

Comment: Done and Done! I used the jsonwebtoken package as you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of the login service need to be the profile info

Comment: and then pass the returned value to the profile component?

Comment: Yo need to save the value in local storage, not in a specific component